# How to extract a matrix from a .fig in Matlab?

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a Matlab **.fig** file. (Basically a pcolor plot). I want to extract the matrix (like rows and columns into an array variable) from this image. How do I do this? Thanks for any inputs or pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axes have a child, which is an object of type [`surface`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitivesurface-properties.html) if you used the `pcolor` function, or of type [`image`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-image-object-and-its-properties.html) if you used the `image` function. The matrix is in the `CData` property of this object:

```
>> x = magic(3) % example data
x =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
>> pcolor(x) % generate image
>> get(get(gca,'Children'),'CData') % retrieve the data
ans =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I understand now

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Luis Mendo's answer, I want to point out that MATLAB supports dot-notation and if performance is any concern, dot-notation should always be preferred over the set()/get() methods.

Using the `handle()` function wrapper along with dot-notation is fastest for both setting and getting of handle class properties.

```
>> x=magic(3)

x =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> pcolor(x)
>> ax = handle(gca);
>> ax.Children.CData

ans =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

For timing experiments and details see: [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/performance-accessing-handle-properties)

Comment: Thanks for the help